# How to import XML data into Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I'm not entirely sure this is even the right question so I apologize if I seem vague. I'll try to explain my situation with the hope of getting some direction in where to begin my research.

If you can tell, I'm just starting out and wanting to expand from just knowing HTML and CSS. I'm working with a startup that just released an API and I'd like to take their data and create a chart in Google Charts/Visualization. Basically they offer a service where users can upload essays and such and they scan it for common grammar mistakes and offer suggestions. Their API does a few things but I'll just be working with a demo call. This demo call just displays an xml page that lists the top ten most frequently used words and the percentage that they're used.

My question is how can I go about using this data (that's stored on their servers) and eventually import it and make a Google Visualization that shows the results? From what I understand Ajax can retrieve this. I've also seen people mention just about every other web programming language under the sun. The jQuery.get() method also looks pretty much like the answer I'm looking for.

I'm slowly working my way through getting a solid understanding of Javascript but really I'd just like some advice on some specific areas to look into more. I'm sure some of you can grasp (through the fog of this question) a lot of holes in my knowledge and can hopefully offer some advice.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed AJAX you're looking for.

jQuery is a Javascript framework, I think it'd be better if you start learning how to do ajax calls in javascript ([here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)), then you'll learn how to do it in jQuery ([here, for example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html)).

Also, [here is](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/the_ajax_respon.html) an example to parse XML datas.

Edit : Browsers do not allow cross-domain requests. There is a hack, though, named JSONP. [This link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) explains it well, and shows examples in javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton! That last link is very helpful. I at least wanted to make sure that Ajax was what I needed to understand before I went ahead. Will I be able to use xmlhttp.open() to make a request that is off-site/server though?

Comment: I cannot believe how easy this is!

Comment: I spoke a little too soon. I've got a pretty good idea of how to make AJAX calls with XMLHTTPRequest and how to parse XML data, but the cross domain thing is where I'm stuck. I'm pretty sure this service doesn't support JSON and only outputs in XML. I've been reading that there's another method involving setting up a proxy with PHP

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. Here is a link that will explain how to do this : http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2682

Comment: @Florian Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)